# How to extract the day of the month using a regular expression in Pandas?

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have strings inside of a dataframe like this

```
140 "14 Feb 1995 Primary Care Doctor:
"
141 "30 May 2016 SOS-10 Total Score:
"
142 "22 January 1996 @ 11 AMCommunication with referring physician?: Done
"
```

And I want to extract days and months separately. So I made a list

```
list=['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec']        
for i in range(500):
     
    for month in list:
       a= 'r(\d\d) '+month+'[a-z]{,8}'
       b=df[0].str.findall(a)[i]
       df['day'][i]=b
```

When I look for df['day'] I get only [] and I would like to get [14] [30] [22]

Comment: use r"...." not "r...."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this pattern:

```
pattern = re.compile(r"(?P<day>\d{1,2}) (?P<month>[A-Z][a-z]{2,}) (?P<year>\d{2,4})")
```

The named capturing groups, like `(?P<day> \d{0,2}` mean you can access the 3-tuple that is returned and extract just that field.

Then you can do something like this:

```
>>> for match in re.finditer(pattern, str):
>>> .... print(match.group("day"))
```

I would also use `apply` rather than a for loop to access your DataFrame:

```
>>> data = {"string": ["14 Feb 1995 Primary Care Doctor:", 
       "30 May 2016 SOS-10 Total Score:",
        "22 January 1996 @ 11 AMCommunication with referring physician?: Done"] }

>>> df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)

>>> df.string.apply(lambda x: re.search(pattern, x).group("day"))

0    14
1    30
2    22
Name: string, dtype: object
```

Then you can conveniently save these values separately if you want to:

```
>>> df["day"] = df.string.apply(lambda x: re.search(pattern, x).group("day"))

>>> df["month"] = df.string.apply(lambda x: re.search(pattern, x).group("month"))

>>> df
    string                                              day month
0   14 Feb 1995 Primary Care Doctor:                    14  Feb
1   30 May 2016 SOS-10 Total Score:                     30  May
2   22 January 1996 @ 11 AMCommunication with refe...   22  January
```

**ETA:** If you want to tweak it to only extract the abbreviated month, regardless of whether it's fully spelled out, try replacing the regex pattern above with this:

```
pattern = re.compile(r"(?P<day>\d{1,2}) (?P<month>[A-Z][a-z]{2})[a-z]*? (?P<year>\d{2,4})")
```

This will capture only the first 3 characters of the month's name, but will find dates even if they have the longer version.

Comment: This is what Im looking for but I get     df["day"] = df['data'].str.apply(lambda x: re.search(pattern, x).group("day"))

AttributeError: 'StringMethods' object has no attribute 'apply'

Comment: Yes -- you can't apply to the `str` version of the column, just use `df["data"].apply( ... )`.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this regex:

```py
...
    a = r"(\d{1,2}) \w+ \d{4}"
    b = df[0].str.findall(a)[i]
    df['day'][i] = b
```